# Work done in accelerating an object in circular motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, acceleration, work

> In a hammer throw competition, an athlete spins a “hammer” before releasing it.
>   The “hammer” used in this sport is a metal ball of mass  = 8 kg and diameter
>    = 30cm, which is attached to a string of length  = 1.2 m. 
>   You may neglect the weight of the string.
>   A world-class athlete can spin the ball up to the speed of  = 30 m/s. Calculate the
>   corresponding work done by the athlete to spin-up the “hammer”, assuming that the
>   “hammer” moves in a horizontal circle of radius  throughout the entire process.

My issue is that I dont see why the answer isnt just $(1/2) mv^2$.

Comment: What is the answer given by your text book?

Comment: @DavidWhite Unfortunately this was a question posed my professor and he hasn't posted the solution. The reason i believe 1/2 mv^2 to be wrong is because it was worth 5 marks so im assuming it cant be just that.

Comment: Based on the work/energy theorem, I also don't see why the answer is not the kinetic energy of the hammer.

Comment: @DavidWhite I just checked a class mates solution. The answer is 1/2mv^2 + an extra term. This term cancels out in the limit where D tends to 0. i.e when we can consider the mass as a point particle. You get it just by calculating the rotational KE.

Comment: Not what was worrying you, but it worried $me$: the mass of a solid metal ball of diameter 30 cm would be over 100 kg for steel and about 40 kg even for aluminium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an extra term because every time you spin the hammer around yourself the hammer itself has rotated once around it's own axis (think of our moon, which always faces us because it's tidally locked). Thus you have your kinetic energy:

$$E_{k}=\frac{1}{2}Mv^{2}$$

But you also have some rotational energy for your hammer about an axis through it's center, which will be of the form:

$$E_{r}=\frac{1}{2}I\omega^{2}$$

The moment of inertia for a solid spherical mass of constant density is $I=\frac{2}{5}MR^{2}$ and your angular rotational speed $\omega$ is one rotation every full rotation of the hammer around the person spinning it:

$$\omega=\frac{v}{2\pi l}$$

Since it's a homework question, I'm sure you can take it from there (:

Comment: This reminds me of a question to which all students gave the wrong answer: A coin is rolled on the inside of a circle. The circumference of the circle is equal to three times the circumference of the coin. The question was how many times the coin made a rotation. All students said three. Because of the curvature of the circle, the coin makes one extra rotation though. So if the coin makes n rotations if the circle were straight, the coin makes one extra rotation if the straight piece is transformed in a circle.